# Open a New HTML Window in Read-Only Mode

Tags: jquery, html

I have linked EtherCalc spreadsheets to my redmine. I hope to make those spreadsheets in *read-only* mode. So I tagged my spreadsheet `iframe` with a read-only `div`. But this solution doesn't work:

```
<div id="my_sheet">
    <iframe src="<%= "http://X.X.X.X:8000/" + @issue.spreedsheet.to_s %>"  width="1000" height="500" style="display: none" id="sheet">frame content.</iframe>
</div>  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_sheet").prop( "readonly", "true" );
})
```

How can I solve this?

Here is my view : [image: spreadsheet]

Comment: There is no such thing as a read-only Iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Just use below css.

```
#my_sheet:after{ 
  position:absolute; 
  content:''; 
  top:0; 
  right:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  left:0;
  z-index:999;
}
#my_sheet{ 
  position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this code works for me, please can you explain a litte bit this code ??

Comment: this is the advantage of pseudo classes. using this class we just create one overlay for iframe

Comment: And its not a valid  solution also. if iframe has scroll then scroll also not working.

Comment: @ krishna: you are right , it's now my problem, the scroll is frozen also with this css code !!!!!!!

Comment: i will give one temporary solution. use this -  #my_sheet:after{  right:20px; }